# Set Environment per Runspace

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, powershell

I am currently working on an application that pulls tasks from a SQL table and exeutes PowerShell scripts. I want to run a `SetUP.ps1` in the beginning to set variables like working dir and so on, and a `tearDown.ps1` in the end just for clean up.

Currently I am using:

```cs
Using myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace
  myRunSpace.Open()

  Using ps = PowerShell.Create
    ps.Runspace = myRunSpace
    ps.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process RemoteSigned")
    ps.Invoke()
  End Using


  Using ps = PowerShell.Create
    ps.Runspace = myRunSpace
    ps.AddScript(Application.StartupPath & "\SetUp.ps1")
    ps.Invoke()
  End Using

  Using ps = PowerShell.Create
    ps.Runspace = myRunSpace
    ps.AddScript(task.Script)
    ReturnValue = PSSerializer.Serialize(ps.Invoke())
  End Using

  Using ps = PowerShell.Create
    ps.Runspace = myRunSpace
    ps.AddScript(Application.StartupPath & "\TearDown.ps1")
    ps.Invoke()
  End Using
End Using
```

In `Setup.ps1` I a currently doing:

```bsh
$env:test = Get-Random
```

When I now run the code above multithreaded with the snippet as code:

```bsh
Start-Sleep 10; $env:test
```

Then all runs give me the same value. the `$env:test` is the same in each run. Is there a way how I can limit the scope of the `$env:test` to simply this one runspace?

Comment: Is any reason why you are using environment instead of standard PowerShell variables?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to accomplish: Have one thread write the random value to an environment variable, and the other thread reading it?

```
Remove-Item c:\test.out -force
Remove-Item Env:\test
$testfile = "c:\test.out"

$myRunSpace = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace()
$myRunSpace.Open()

$ps1 = [PowerShell]::Create()
$ps1.Runspace = $myRunSpace
$ps1.AddScript("`$env:test = Get-Random")


$ps1.Invoke()

$ps2 = [PowerShell]::Create()
$ps2.Runspace = $myRunSpace
$ps2.AddScript("Start-Sleep -Seconds 1")
$ps2.AddScript("`$env:test | Out-File $testfile")
$ps2.Invoke()

start-sleep 2
"variable set to: $env:test"
"file reads: " + (Get-Content $testfile)
```